# Why does autoconf erroneously find a function which isn't available later?

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf

On a Linux system I configured a software package (llvm) and autoconf finds the `arc4random` function. Here an extraction of the output during configuration:

```
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strerror_r... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for arc4random... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for strtoq... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
```

Configuring goes fine. Later, when building the package I get an error about an undeclared specifier `arc4random`:

```
[removed]/lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc:368:10: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'arc4random'
  return arc4random();
         ^
```

Here the referred location:

```
367 #if defined(HAVE_ARC4RANDOM)
368   return arc4random();
369 #else
370   static int x = (::srand(GetRandomNumberSeed()), 0);
371   (void)x;
372   return ::rand();
373 #endif
```

It's properly guarded, here the `configure.ac` piece:

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strerror strerror_r setenv arc4random ])
```

Seems all fine. I am wondering why the configure process detected the function to be available.

autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.63

Here the extract from `config.log`:

```
configure --prefix=[removed] --host=powerpc64-bgq-linux --disable-terminfo --disable-zlib --enable-targets=powerpc CXX=bgclang++ CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fPIC CC=bgclang CFLAGS=-O3 -fPIC LDFLAGS=-shared
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [`arc4random(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/arc4random), to use this function, you should include `<bsd/stdlib.h>` in your code and link it with `-lbsd`.

What this `AC_CHECK_FUNCS([... arc4random ])` does is to make sure `arc4random` exists in your system, then define the macro named `HAVE_ARC4RANDOM`, but it cannot guarantee your code is using it correctly.