# What does autoconf actually run for the AC_CHECK_FUNCS functionality

Tags: c, autotools

Say in `configure.ac` I check for the availability of a C function, like

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS( [arc4random] )
```

And later the configure process is positive on this function:

```
checking for arc4random... yes
```

What does the configure process actually run (say on a Linux system)? Does it construct a sample program and tries to compile it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183412/why-does-autoconf-erroneously-find-a-function-which-isnt-available-later doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It generates a test program that declares a function with the same name, then compiles and link it. Change a few characters in the name of the function (to make the test fail) and check config.log, you'll see the source code of the test program when it fails.